# How do I serialize a generated class?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization, orm, code-generation

I am working on a project and I would like to send an entity from the database through a web service.

I have this as my data contract.

```
[DataContract]
public class CreateAlumniRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Alum.Data.EmploymentHistory> lstEmploymentHistory;
}
```

However, I keep getting this error.

> Type
>   'Alum.Data.Base.EmploymentHistoryBase'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking
>   it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the
>   type is a collection, consider marking
>   it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.

Which tells me I probably need to go to the EmploymentHistory class and mark it as a DataContract.

The problem is EmploymentHistory is generated by an inhouse ORM tool - I can't really make any changes to it.

Is it possible to make serialize EmploymentHistory without adding that attribute in the class?

Is there any other solution? The only thing I can think of doing is re-creating EmploymentHistory in a serializable class and manually mapping the objects, which sounds like a lot of duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which serializer you are trying to use but if Alum.Data.EmploymentHistory can't be serialized because it isn't marked as serializable or for some other reason... should be able to just right click on it and extract the interface.  Using create a class to implement the interface using the refactoring menu and have just implement {get;set;} on the members.  Then you could use [automapper](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/01/22/automapper-the-object-object-mapper.aspx) to map the data over.

It sound like alot but it actually would be really quick... and would avoid all the manual mapping.  Even if you don't use automapper for this it is definitely worth looking at.  There are so many situations where you need to copy data from one object to another... the "AssertConfigurationIsValid" makes testing your mapping easy.  If you arrays or lists or any kind of nested objects things are handled automagically ... very cool... check it out.

Comment: that's probably what i'll have to do. I just don't like the fact that if EmploymentHistory ever changes, I'll have to remember to re-map the variables across.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If your codegenerator creates partial classes you can add the missing attribute to new partial files.</strike>

If not you can try a different open source serialiser like [SharpSerializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) or [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Comment: You could add an interface implementation using this method, but you cannot add attributes to properties already declared in the generated file. This is why the DataAnnotations provided us with the buddy-class method, which I don't think is supported with WCF. But still, creating an interface containing all the properties defined in the generated file and then apply it in the partial class would work.

Comment: The [DataContract] attribute isn't necessarly required for a serializable type, but WCF obviously encountered a part or property of the EmploymentHistory class, which it probably can't serialize. In that case [DataMember] would be required on some properties.